# correct regex synthax in custom bbcode apllication

Tags: php, regex

I wish to integrated the prism synthax highlighter into my custom built php/mysql CMS; however i am having some issues with regex synthax.
This is what i wish to accomplish:

- Allow users to post

  - text alone,
  - or code and text but never code alone.
- Code may be preceded by text or text may be included after the code.

My PHP Code is below:

```
function bbcode2html($var)
{
    // [code]
    $var = preg_replace('/\[code](.+?)\[\/code]/si',
    '<section class="language-markup">
          <pre><code>$1</code></pre>
     </section>', $var);
    return $var;
}
$var = '[code]<!DOCTYPE html>[/code] THis is text';

// verify content input
if(!preg_match("/(w+?)|\[code](.+?)\[\/code]/si", $var))
{
    echo 'The code tags can not be empty!';
}
elseif(!preg_match("/(w+?)|\[code](.+?)\[\/code](w+)/si", $var))
{
    echo 'Your post contains only code, please add some text';
}else{
echo $var = bbcode2html(htmlentities($var));}
```

With the present code above, this is what i have observed the following:

- When text alone is posted, i get this feedback 'The code tags can not be empty!'
- When text and code are posted, i get this feed back 'Your post contains only code, please add some text'

I therefore need clues as to the right regex synthax that will enable me achieve these two objectives:

- Allow users to post text alone, or code and text but never code alone.
- Code may be preceded by text or text may be included after the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about doing two checks:

- Verify the string contains one [[[:alnum:]]](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), after stripping all `[code]...[/code]` and trimming.
- Check for empty code tags

See [example on eval.in](https://eval.in/152220)

```
$var = '[code]<!DOCTYPE html>[/code] THis is text';

// code alone or nothing
if(!preg_match('~[[:alnum:]]~', trim(preg_replace('~\[code\].*?\[/code\]~', "", $var))))
{
    echo 'Please add some text...';
} else {

    // empty code tags
    if(preg_match('~\[code\]\s*\[/code\]~', $var))
    {
        echo 'The code tags can not be empty!';

    // fine
    } else {
        echo "wohoOoo it works!";
    }
}
```